# Session variable lost doing Url.action call from Jquery Dialog code

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, session

I have a very strange problem regarding the above in IE10 running from VS 2013 on Win7 x64.

The session persists over the requests when I simply hit OK in internet options! It breaks when I rebuild the app. Hitting OK again in internet options returns it to working order until rebuilt and on it goes.

So far I have:
- set IE to check for newer versions of stored pages: Every time I visit the page
- cleared the cache using dev tools
- checked the same .NET framework is targeted from each project and, they are full versions, not client profile.
- stopped the application caching with this code

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
{
    //Used for disabling page caching
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
}
```

The session variables are being set and retrieved with following code I found on line

```
public class SessionManager
{
    //Session variable constants
    public const string DATEFORMATVAR = "DisplayDateFormat";

    //use generics to work with any type
    public static T Read<T>(string variable)
    {
        object value = HttpContext.Current.Session[variable];
        if (value == null)
            return default(T);
        else
            return ((T)value);
    }

    public static void Write(string variable, object value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[variable] = value;
    }

    public static string DisplayDateFormat
    {
        get
        {
            return Read<string>(DATEFORMATVAR);
        }
        set
        {
            Write(DATEFORMATVAR, value);
        }
    }
```

Does anybody have any idea what could be causing the loss of session and, why OK in the browser settings makes it work?

Thanks for reading

**UPDATE**
After further investigation I have established the session variable value is lost from the following jQuery Dialog code. I have checked the session value before and after the url.action call and it is being lost here.

```
        //jQuery Customer Selection from Customer Notes page
        $("#cn-btn-cust-slt").button().click(function () {
            $("#cn-dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: true,
                position: { my: "left", at: "top+350", of: window },
                width: 700,
                height: 600,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Customer Selection',
                modal: true,
                open: function () {
                    $(this).load('@Url.Action("CustNotesSearchJqDia", "Customer")');
                },
                buttons: {
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Has anybody any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Are you using cookie-less sessions?

Comment: Wize - no, cookies have not been disabled. I've isolated it a little further and ruled out url.action. This code $(this).load("/Customer/CustNotesSearchJqDia"); also loses session - it looks like I have a problem with jquery dialog losing session! Thanks for the reply - any idea?